# Verification or authentication process of advertising viewed on the browser

Tags: javascript, rest, encryption, authorization

Introduction:
   I am rewarding users for watching videos and advertising.  On the client page, whenever an ad is completely watched, the page will call a function adWatched(), which tells the server to give a certain amount of money to the user.

Problem:
    I can not prevent someone from writing a script to automatically call adWatched(), even without watching the ad.  Anyone has an idea of how to do this?

- My ad network does not communicate to my server whenever an ad impression is delivered
- I have tried using auth tokens, where I send an auth token whenever a new page is created.  Fraudsters can just call page.reload() to get this auth token and then adWatched()
- Code Minify helps, but can't prevent a sniffer from seeing the calls.
- This action happens millions of times a day, so any solution has to be light on the database/CPU or highly efficient

Details:
   desktop website application written in .NET/javascript/HTML

Comment: Ethan, is there something on JWPlayer's server side that keeps track of ad impressions watched at an instance level?